# MPDF html to pdf conversion tables appear shrinked

Tags: php, mpdf

[image]

It should look like here http://outsource.gestionminute.com/htmltopdf/form/service.html

Highly appreciated for help,

```
$url = 'http://outsource.gestionminute.com/htmltopdf/form/test.html';
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['mode' => 'utf-8', 'format' => 'A4-L']);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
```

Comment: Can you provide what `$html` contains ?

Comment: Can you check now, Have updated the code